# how to Integrate zephyr for Jira, execute test cases & update results in jira automatically

Tags: jenkins, automated-tests, integration-testing, jira, jira-zephyr

I have hosted jira & jenkins servers seperately & integrated them using 'jira for jenkins' & 'jenkins for jira' plugins. I'm using zephyr for jira plugin with jira for test management but I don't find that working. I have googled and tried various steps for automatically updating the test results in jira once I click on the execute button from jira where my test scripts are in github

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your interest in Zephyr. We are from Zephyr Support and the issue that you are facing seems can be handled well if you can raise a ticket with us and if we can go over a call or screen share meeting.
Please sign up to our support site "support.getzephyr.com/hc/en-us" using your company email id and use the option "Submit a Case" to raise a ticket with us and one of our support engineers would immediately contact you. It's a better channel to keep track of Zephyr issues.

Let us know if you are facing any difficulty in raising the ticket and we can raise it on behalf of you.

Meanwhile we are not sure if you are aware of the Jenkins plugin for Zephyr for Jira. Please check the link below

https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Zephyr+For+Jira+Test+Management+Plugin

Thanks
Zephyr Support

Comment: the plugin creates new test for each test run, that would be an overkill, can we avoid a way to avoid creating new test for each run?

Comment: It would be great to be able to have indeed constant test JIRA IDs, for example extracted from Junit testsuite id attributes. Then automated test development cycle is possible with:
 - create Zephyr test in JIRA
 - implement test in whatever framework, making sure the JIRA ID is passed in testsuite id
 - run automated test in Jenkins
 - Jenkins updating automatically the test results in JIRA

Comment: @Zephyr Support  is there a way to link the junit test case result with that of zephyr test case ? instead of new test for each test run ?